# Unable to send more than 5 emails to Exchange server using JavaMail

Tags: email, smtp, jakarta-mail, exchange-server

I have a method that sends many emails to exchange server over smtp using JavaMail, below is my code,

```
public void sendMail(){
        final String host="host",port="587",username="mail1@local.local",password="password",from="";
        try {

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
            props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", host);

            final String email = from;

            Authenticator authenticator = new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                 return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            };

            Session session = Session.getInstance(props,authenticator);
            InternetAddress replyToAddress [] = new InternetAddress[1];
            replyToAddress[0] = new InternetAddress("mail1@local.local");
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
            mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress("mail1@local.local"));
            mimeMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("mail2@local.local"));
            mimeMessage.setSubject("Test");
            mimeMessage.setText("Hello Testing");

            mimeMessage.setReplyTo(replyToAddress);
            transport.send(mimeMessage);
            System.out.println("Email has been Sent Successfully to");
       } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now when I apply a loop and call this function 10 times then only first five emails are sent successfully, for rest of the request I get the following exception,

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2157)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2144)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.close(SMTPTransport.java:1210)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:197)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
```

if I increase the request count then still only first five emails are sent, rest of them throws the exception.

If I put the failed request in some queue and retry them later then some of them will be sent.

Any clue will be appreciated, do I need to check for some configuration on Exchange server?

Comment: Have you tried to change your code to [only establish the connection once](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#rptsend) to send multiple messages?

Comment: First, you should read [this JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) and fix the common mistakes.  Reusing a connection to send multiple messages might help.  It's almost certainly the Exchange server that's stopping you because you're sending too much mail or creating too many connections in too short a time or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

We have seen this exact same issue with a  MS Exchange Server 2010. We had to increase the  ReceiveConnector message rate limit by issuing the following Powershell-command:

```
Set-ReceiveConnector "Client CLIENTNAME" -MessageRateLimit unlimited
```